# I am trying to execute a java code which will execute the following regEx, but not able get the desired result. Its never going in the if() block

Tags: java, regex

```
<https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/{org-slug}/{project-slug}/issues/?&cursor=1619685938645:0:1>; rel="previous"; results="false"; cursor="1619685938645:0:1", <https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/theloops/java-project/issues/?&cursor=1618813765615:1:0>; rel="next"; results="true"; cursor="1618813765615:1:0"
```

Above is the code in which I need to capture second "results" element and see whether its true or not, I am trying

```
String link = "<https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/{org-slug}/{project-slug}/issues/?&cursor=1619685938645:0:1>; rel=\"previous\"; results=\"false\"; cursor=\"1619685938645:0:1\", <https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/theloops/java-project/issues/?&cursor=1618813765615:1:0>; rel=\"next\"; results=\"true\"; cursor=\"1618813765615:1:0\"";
    log.info(link);
    if(link.matches("/\\(?+1\\).+(results)=\"true\"/"))
        bool = true; //(bool is a boolean)
```

but the variable 'bool' is not getting true

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In java, unlike many other languages, the [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method only returns `true` if the *entire* String is matched by the regex. This is usually achieved by adding `.*` to each end of the regex.

Also, in no flavor of regex do forward slashes have any special meaning, although *some* languages allow slashes to *delimit* regex (java is not one of them), so they should not be used as the first and last character unless you actually want to match slashes there.

To know if the 2nd `results` is `true`:

```
bool = link.matches(".*results=.*results=\"true\".*"))
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/VNV15eVggVbLph).

Note the removal of unnecessary brackets too.

Comment: Thanks allot @Bohemian, your suggestion was to the point and its working fine :-)

Comment: Here I want to get value of second occurance of "result" because I need only 'result' of rel=next; but in this case it will also check first occurance of result=true and get satisfied and return true.

Comment: @Akshay No. This regex ignores the first "results" and only matches when the second "results" is "true". See demo linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this regEx more useful:

```
"results=\"([a-z]+)\";\\s+cursor=\"([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\""
```